# Add expiration to C# windows application

Tags: c#

i am trying to make make app expire after some days using the registry option, i have successfully written and read from registry, my issue is to check for expiration, below is my code:

```
 regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Systemfiles");//subkeyname
            if (regKey == null)
            {
                regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Systemfiles");
                regKey.SetValue("tere", Encrypt("4/16/2017"));
            }
            else
            {
                regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Systemfiles");//subkeyname
                string decryptDateValue = Decrypt(regKey.GetValue("tere").ToString());  //Keyname
                DateTime mainDate = Convert.ToDateTime(decryptDateValue);

                DateTime expiringDate = mainDate.AddDays(1);
                if (mainDate > expiringDate)
                {
                    expire = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Continue execution
                }
            }
```

from my code i assumed the user's first run is the 04/16/2017, i also assumed i want the user to run the application for one day, which supposed to expire on the 04/17/2017, meaning if the user tries to start the application after 04/17/2017 the if part should execute, but i am not really getting it right, the else part always execute, i will appreciate a better way of doing it. Thanks

Comment: Try `if (DateTime.Now>expiringDate)`

Comment: You're constructing `expiringDate` from `mainDate` by adding days. They will therefore always have a fixed relationship with regards to `>`.

Comment: Let's put your current check into words. Assume `mainDate` has a date `04/16/2017`. `expiringDate` is `mainDate` plus an extra day i.e. `04/17/2017`. Then you check `if (mainData > expiringDate) {` or, in other words: `if (04/16/2017 > 04/17/2017) {`. As @Pikoh said, you should check if the current `DateTime` is bigger than the `expiringDate`.

Comment: i dont want to use the system date, just to avoid users changing their system date

Comment: In that case you could use an external Time API (such as TimezoneDB https://timezonedb.com/api) to fetch the current time.

Comment: So, how are you going to know when a user opens your application? Either you use the system time, or you need to use a internet time server

Comment: @UwakMfon - whatever you do, based on your current approach, users will find ways to bypass if they're determined enough. E.g. even if I'd not seen your source I can decompile your code and realise that wiping a registry key will give me the "new user" experience once again.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, please what is the best approach in doing this apart from the internet option, because i don't want internet to be a condition for running the application

Comment: @UwakMfon - consider the worlds of computer games and movies, the *considerable* efforts that have gone into protecting them and yet the fact that they *still* get pirated. You can't win when the code is running on *someone else's machine*. If you want to stand a chance, I'd recommend you look to *buy* a licensing system rather than trying to build one yourself from scratch, but even then recognize that in the absence of internet/server involvement, people *will* find ways to bypass it.

Comment: @UwakMfon the best approach in my opinion is not doing anything. As Damien has already told, users with just a bit more than basic knowledge would find a way to bypass your protection. For basic users, using system date should be enough

Answer (score 2):

You've got this in your code:

```
DateTime expiringDate = mainDate.AddDays(1);
if (mainDate > expiringDate)
```

So,`expiringDate` would always be bigger than `mainDate` (one day exactly).

What you want to check is the actual Date, so it should be:

```
if (DateTime.Now>expiringDate)
```